# WSProxy setClientId in Child BU does not allow execute at Parent BU

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, ssjs

In SF Marketing Cloud, I'm trying to update a subscriber at the Parent BU Level from my SSJS in the Child BU.

I created a Cloud Page at the Child BU to run the following code in order to debug faster.

```
<script  runat="server">

Platform.Load("core","1.1.5");
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

//Switch context to different BU. Change the MID to suit.
  prox.setClientId({"ID":XXXXXXXXX});
  var props = [
{Name:"SubscriberKey", Value:"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"},
{Name:"ListID", Value:XX},
{Name:"DoNotTrack", Value:"True"}];

var data = prox.execute(props, "Log Update Subscriber property");
Write(Stringify(data));
</script>
```

I received the following message in the response

```
{"Status":"Error","RequestID":"a88391ed-04e8-4590-a77e-2ad220c1b8b9","Results":[{"StatusCode":"Error","StatusMessage":"RequestID: a88391ed-04e8-4590-a77e-2ad220c1b8b9  Message: MemberID 1000XXXXX does not have access to ClientID: ID[10000XXXX] PartnerClientKey[] UserID[] PartnerUserKey[] supplied in the request","OrdinalID":0,"Results":null,"ErrorCode":0}]}
```

**Error Message:MemberID 1000XXXXX does not have access to ClientID: ID[10000XXXX]**

MemberID 1000XXXXX is my Child BU where the code is running
ClientID: ID[10000XXXX] is the Parent BU

**Question: Does the WSProxy impersonate the parent BU from a Child BU or that's not possible (it's not mentioned in the documentation)?

Am I missing something?**

**Note: I tested to run my code at the Parent Level and impersonate the Child BU and the code was running successfully.**

Comment: I have tested and receive the same results. It seems only Parent to Child impersonation is possible now, which is very limiting. Child to Parent was possible at one point, and it seems SF changed something recently. Perhaps from a security perspective it was an issue.

Comment: I used the REST API to solve my problem via an SSJS Activity.